# Notepad++ updater had no title or info. Is this okay?

Tags: malware, software

While updating Notepad++, the updater window showed no title or information. Is this okay from security point of view ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This is perfectly fine.**

When a program opens a window, it sends to it a few parameters including the window title, main text, button labels, etc. In this case, it seems like the updater simply hasn't given any such information. It's silly from a UI point of view, but there are no security implications with this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your software offers a GPG signature so that you can [verify](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html) you did not download a malware.

You can also check your HTTP requests while updating.